# Can I change a .NET core environment variable (specifically ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT) at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, build, devops

Apparently I'm meant to have the same artefact (produced using dotnet publish/build) for both dev and prod setups, but obviously I want dev and prod to have a different ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT setting.

All the instructions to set this envvar I have found are for dotnet build/publish/run.

Is there a way to set it when running a dll (using dotnet ...dll)?

Thanks

Comment: The artifacts produced by publish/build don't know about the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` setting. As the name tells you the value is set by the environment e.g. the machine/container you are running the app on. Why do you need think you need to change it at runtime?

Comment: Do you know how to set environment variables from the computer you're running the dll on?